# WildFly - Creating dataSource in domain mode requires restart

Tags: java, wildfly

I have been trying WildFly as application server for a production enviroment, however I have few doubts that I can't answer with the documentation or previous questions.

In the domain mode using the same machine, I have created two server group that are containing one server each one, this is with the idea of isolate two different production enviroments. The problem with the dataSource, is that obviously I have to create them in the profile associated to the server group, but always that I create a new dataSource I need to restart de group, this is a problem since I can't restart the servers for doing this.

Is there a way to do this in a more friendly way?

I'm currently using WildFly 13 and the HAL console to admin the servers.

Comment: Just to understand. After you add a new datasource in your profile, do you want that servers see this new datasource without a restart of your servers?  Or the servers don't need to see this datasource's update?

Comment: @ThiagoChagas In any moment I can add a new application, so yes, I have to be able to create new JNDI datasources in the future without the need of restart the server

Comment: All your servers under the same profile will be affected for that datasource update( and this make sense). Workaround: If you don't want to have any interference, you will need another profile for that (you could use the 'profile copy') . But of course, if this profile is updated too, the servers will need a restart.